# How can I properly loop with arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning arrays through here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays#active_learning_printing_those_products!

I've given my take for their assignment and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong, despite using their Show Solution option.

```
const list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
const totalBox = document.querySelector('.output p');
let total = 0;
list.innerHTML = '';
totalBox.textContent = '';
// number 1
let products = ['Underpants:6.99',
                'Socks:5.99',
                'T-shirt:14.99',
                'Trousers:31.99',
                'Shoes:23.99'];
                
// number 2
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
// number 3
  let prices = products[i].split(':');
  let stringPrices = Number(prices);


  for (let z = 0; z < stringPrices.length; z++) {
// number 4
    let total[z] += stringPrices
  }

// number 5
  let itemText = `${products[i] — ${prices[i]}` ;

  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = itemText;
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}

totalBox.textContent = 'Total: $' + total.toFixed(2);
```

The output should eventually be:

- Underpants — $6.99
- Socks — $5.99
- T-shirt — $14.99
- Trousers — $31.99
- Shoes — $23.99

Would very much appreciate your feedback. Thank you kindly

Comment: Please add relevant HTML to create a [mre]

Comment: use ```let prices = products[i].split(':')[1]``` but I didn't understand what are you trying with the loop of stringPrice.

Comment: @Bulent With stringPrices loop I'm trying to get total to add to each and every price, as requested in question number 4 of the assignment. Perhaps the loop is not necesary at all and I'm confused?

Comment: Please add the result you needed, or your expectation from this code
What you are expecting from "let stringPrices = Number(prices);"  "let total[z] += stringPrices" "let itemText = `${products[i] — ${prices[i]}` ;"
It looks like all these 3 code could return some error

Comment: @ChrisG Hi Chris, I couldn't include relevant HTML because I wasn't provided with such as this is taken off a live output assignment of a website.

Comment: @sojin Edited main post with what the output should eventually be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const list = document.querySelector('.output ul');
const totalBox = document.querySelector('.output p');
let total = 0;
list.innerHTML = '';
totalBox.textContent = '';
// number 1
let products = ['Underpants:6.99',
                'Socks:5.99',
                'T-shirt:14.99',
                'Trousers:31.99',
                'Shoes:23.99'];
          
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  let prices = products[i].split(':');
  let itemText = `${products[i]} - ${prices[1]}`;
  total += parseFloat(prices[1])
  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.textContent = itemText;
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}

totalBox.textContent = 'Total: $' + total.toFixed(2);
```

Try this one

Comment: Thank you, sojin. For me to understand, can you please explain why my   for (let z = 0; z < stringPrices.length; z++) {
// number 4
    let total[z] += stringPrices
  }  loop is not necessary for each price to add to the total?

Comment: Check the loop. String prices will only contain the price of one item in the product 
not the prices of all items, also when you are splitting the product its first index will contain the product name and second index will contain the price, you don't need to loop it again

Comment: let total[z] += stringPrices 
also this is completely wrong
1. you have already defined the total in the top, 2. you are looping the stringPrices and trying to add stringPrices itself, 3)  total[z] i dint understand what you mean by this